# Is there a proper term for lists of removable tags?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, tags

I call them "tag blocks" but I don't think that's correct. The pattern is a block of textual information with the X to remove it. It can be seen in some places after adding a file to let you remove the file.

Pinterest uses this pattern to section off the search terms.
[image: Pinterest]

For Best Buy they show up after you select filters from the facets on the left.
[image: Best Buy]

Comment: these are called: TAGS !

Comment: They're all tags in tag listings. The first are description tags, the second are filter tags

Answer (score 12):

They receive many names depending on the script you use, there seems NOT to be a consensus on a single specific name. Just to illustrate different options, here you have the names and link to the script that generates these blocks.

[Tags Input](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)

[Token Input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

[Tag Selector](http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/)

[Select Box](https://select2.github.io/) and also [select box](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

There seems to be some kind of consistent naming around the *tag* and *select* terms, however it's not definitive. Furthermore, since most of these plugins (if not all) use JQuery and "selector" is a totally different thing in JQuery (and HTML5) while *select* is even more confusing, I guess something like **tag box** would be the more appropriate option. Personally, I call them *closable terms boxes*

## These are not tags

To be clear: these are not **tags**, nor are these **select**, these are not **boxes**, these are not **selectors**. All of this terms have very specific definitions, none of them apply to the question entirely, only in part.

Furthermore, this element is NOT always a tag, it could be a category, or a custom taxonomy or a live search term.

## Anatomy of element

**This element is composed of at least 3 different sub-elements**: *a visual one, a taxonomy/IA one and an action one.*

**The visual one** is the box or boundary that contains the tag or filter term plus the *close* element, **the taxonomy one** is the term itself (eg, a tag), and **the action one** is the *close* element and in some cases, a *handle* to drag an re-arrange.

Functionally, it's an **input** element if you work with *autocomplete search* or the likes, but if the terms were added by an admin, they are **select** since the user can only select from a pre-defined list of terms.

## In short

As said above, there's no consensus about it. If you're looking to properly communicate this element to someone, it's reasonable to call them by combining 2 or more of the compounding parts

Comment: *"... this element is NOT always a tag, it could be a category, or a custom taxonomy ..."*  < but isn't a category or taxo just a series meta tags positioned within an IA? Live search is a different matter, but I don't recall seeing this presentation used in that circumstance often.

Comment: @plainclothes, I have a very different understanding of what a taxonomy is in terms of structural organization, but I understand what you mean. As a matter of fact, I tried to provide a more known approach (eg, the IA widely known CMSs use, such as WordPress or Joomla) than what I understand, but what you say is correct depending the paradigm you want to use

Comment: I'd argue that **they are always a tag, just different types of it**. Sometimes description tags, sometimes filter tags, sometimes category tags, etc.

Comment: In material design, they're called Chips.

Answer (score 5):

They're called **tags** or **tag buttons**.

It's so inherent in so many OSs that you can just call them tags. We just had a client saying they want **dismissable tags** in such and such ... so you could perhaps refer to them as that more fully.

Great question!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Material design called them "Chips". https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html

Answer (score 2):

## Breadbox

Russell<sup>1</sup> calls this **breadbox** although in the book these are styled a plain list rather than tags. But that's a stylistic difference (see the *Your Selection* box):

[image: A screenshot of the food network site, where a box with current filters and an option to remove each is given]

<sup>1</sup>Russell-Rose, T., 2013. *Designing the Search Experience*. Morgan Kaufmann, Amsterdam.

Comment: Hay @Izhaki .. is there some confusion?  In the image you posted, what are you actually referring to?  there seems to be no connection to the question - what am I missing?

Comment: The section titled "Your selections". It's `breadbox` in contrast to `bread crumb`.

Answer (score 2):

Before flat design became in vogue, during the heyday of gradients, drop-shadows and reflections, tags wrapped inside round cornered rectangles were often referred to as Lozenges in certain circles. 
This term was a way to distinguish between a button and a list of tags which are clickable. 
That said, I've not heard the term mentioned in the last couple of years.

Comment: That horrible term came from Apple's silly little pill-shaped buttons, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons? There's no specific term for it. The first example are tags. The second are filters. They just happen to be styled as buttons/boxes.

UPDATE: Joe makes me realize that what these are called would depend on what we're talking about.

- Individual words or phrases to provide meta-data to content: tags
- Terms used to reduce a search data set: filters
- An 'x' to delete an item: delete?
- A visual box you can interact with: button?

I'd say your images are examples of **(functionally) tags and filters that can be easily dismissed with the delete icon and (stylistically) displayed as buttons** :)

Comment: These are called tags dude. (Or  - sure - tag buttons, etc.)  Maybe I'm misinterpreting this question.  Maybe you've had too much Chardonnay today  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow in the first example, the *content* is a tag. But not all tags have this visual style. The second *could* be called a tag, but it's being used in the context of a *filter*. It's all subjective of course and mostly dependent on context.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a particularly well established terminology for them, but I've generally heard them referred to as **pills**.

The naming confusion comes from the fact that the most common use for the **pill** UI pattern is to *represent* tags. It's easy to spot why folks would drift to using the common usage to describe the pattern.  *Pills* work really well for *tags*, but they work really well for other things too - Emails, IP addresses, etc...

So, "pill" or "pill input" is the ui pattern that's often used to provide tagging capability, but which can be used for other things too.